# Why is the strongest postcondition for a program that just allocates x "exists x :: P"

Tags: hoare-logic

I'm working my way through Leino's "Program Proofs" and I was following as far as the semantics of variable assignment, but I'm not quite sure why this is a valid Hoare triple:

{forall x::Q} var x; {exists x :: P}

where P is the weakest precondition and Q is the strongest postcondition.  I'm not following why allocating x guarantees that there exists an x that satisfies P.